# Virto Commerce API - How to retrieve products by period created date

Tags: c#, virtocommerce

Now i need retrieve products follow creation date (from - to) to show its in store front
Have API or Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Liquid** `Sort` filter for this task.

```
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products | sort:"createdDate:desc" %}
```